# Magento 2 - Uncaught Error: Class "DOMDocument"

Tags: magento, magento2, domdocument, magento2.4

I am using magento commerce cloud, and when I try to execute selected command below:

> vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests

Then this error is shown in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Class "DOMDocument" not found in ../vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Config/Dom.php:366
```

All solutions online are pointing to the same thing, php extensions **dom** and **xml** are missing. I installed both of them through DockerFile in config/php folder and when I checked enabled php extensions with php -i. **Both are installed**.

But error still happens again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a php file with phpinfo() and check both extensions there + running the composer update once you are sure the extensions are present.